# ¿Cómo hacer que los datos que se han añadido a la base de datos sean persistentes?

Tags: docker, storage, neo4j

Quiero que mis datos sean persistentes en el contenedor Docker en el que estoy construyendo una base de datos neo4j. Sin embargo, las órdenes que he encontrado no parecen aplicarse a mi situación. En efecto parace que debemos hacer:

```
docker run -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 neo4j --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data
```

Pero en mi caso no hay neo4 en $HOME:

```
bash-5.1$ cd $HOME/
.bash_history    .config/         Documents/       .gitkraken/      .gphoto/         .lesshst         Music/           Public/          Templates/       .wget-hsts       
.cache/          Desktop/         Downloads/       .gnome/          .ipython/        .local/          Pictures/        .ssh/            Videos/          
.cert/           .docker/         .gitconfig       .gnupg/          .jupyter/        .mozilla/        .pki/            Téléchargements/ .vscode/
```

Por lo tanto ya hé una imagen neo4j y funciona muy bien:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 neo4j
2022-01-14 11:11:24.351+0000 INFO  Starting...
2022-01-14 11:11:25.469+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.3.6 ========
2022-01-14 11:11:26.639+0000 INFO  Initializing system graph model for component 'security-users' with version -1 and status UNINITIALIZED
2022-01-14 11:11:26.643+0000 INFO  Setting up initial user from defaults: neo4j
2022-01-14 11:11:26.643+0000 INFO  Creating new user 'neo4j' (passwordChangeRequired=true, suspended=false)
2022-01-14 11:11:26.652+0000 INFO  Setting version for 'security-users' to 3
2022-01-14 11:11:26.654+0000 INFO  After initialization of system graph model component 'security-users' have version 3 and status CURRENT
2022-01-14 11:11:26.657+0000 INFO  Performing postInitialization step for component 'security-users' with version 3 and status CURRENT
2022-01-14 11:11:26.967+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2022-01-14 11:11:27.680+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2022-01-14 11:11:27.681+0000 INFO  Started.
```

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta ¿qué es lo que "has" y funciona muy bien? ¿Está resuelto entonces el problema? La sintaxis correcta para lanzar el contenedor sería la primera, aún si esa carpeta no existe. Docker la creará y la usará como almacén persistente externo al contenedor. Siempre que relances con esa opción, volverá a usar esa carpeta externa, por lo que la base de datos persistirá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lanzas este comando te tiene que lanzar un error por pantalla:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 neo4j --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data
error: exec: "--volume=/home/msalinas/neo4j/data:/data": stat --volume=/home/msalinas/neo4j/data:/data: no such file or directory
```

Esto ocurre porque las opciones en `docker run` las tienes que pasar antes del nombre de la imagen ([documentación del comando](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)):

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Si lo lanzas poniendo el nombre de la imagen al final funcionará sin problemas:

```
docker run -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data neo4j
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Tengo un mensaje de warnings : `Warning: Folder mounted to "/data" is not writable from inside container. Changing folder owner to neo4j.` ¿Puede evitar que mis datos sean persistentes?

Comment: Si, si no tiene permisos no va a poder guardar los datos. Haz lo que te dice de cambiar al usuario de la carpeta a neo4j. Será algo como `sudo chown neo4j:neo4j neo4j/data`

Comment: Muchas gracias, y a donde van los datos si no hico `--volume` ...

Comment: Si no puede poner una "conexión" entre el contenedor y la carpeta en el ordenador que lo ejecuta se quedarán los datos dentro del contenedor. Poniendo los permisos correspondientes a la carpeta del ordenador "padre" que quieres usar como volumen en el contenedor (en tu caso `$HOME/neo4j/data`)  se te quedarán ya guardados en tu ordenador (y no dentro del contenedor que se perderán en el momento en el que ese contenedor desaparezca).